# How to sum up values in a HashMap<String, <String,Integer>>?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a following HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String,Integer>> dataArray = new HashMap<>();
```

In the program, I do use enhanced loop to iterate few times and insert data into the HashMap, based on some kind of key, as in:

```
dataArray.get(primaryKey).put(length, totalCost)
```

It produces the following output:

```
{123-456-789={00:05:00=500, 00:01:06=220}, 999-090-090={00:08:01=900}}
```

I use a formula to calculate the `totalCost` value, but I have to make sure it is set to 0 at each iteration's beginning.

My question is, I want to sum up `totalCost` and `length` values for each `primaryKey`. The end result should be something like this:

```
{123-456-789={00:06:06=720}, 999-090-090={00:08:01=900}}
```

How would I accomplish that? Do I have to create another HashMap, or is it possible to modify the ones already existing? With a loop perhaps?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that if I try to obtain existing `totalCost` value with `dataArray.get(primaryKey).get(totalCost)`, compiler complains about a suspicious call to `java.util.Map` and returns `null`.

Comment: You mean, like this? [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/v4j6ki)

Comment: That definitely helped, thank you!

Comment: @Andreas, if you posted it as an answer, it could be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why so complicated? Just alter your data-structure. OOP is meant to solve precisely that problem. Just store the subtables in an Object each and provide appropriate methods/variables. As for inserting the data into the existing `Map`: How would you distinguish the resulting sums from what you inserted as standard-values? In addition this would quite likely cause a concurrent modification, though there are ways to work around that.

Comment: I am unfortunately unable to alter the data-structure, it has to be the way I described. I am aware that I could use objects to achieve that, but I am unable to do so due to limits that I cannot affect in any way.

Comment: In that case your best shot is a second `Map` for storing the results. For that one you can at least use a `Pair' as value-type.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to obtain existing values of `length` and `totalCost` and simply sum them and the new ones, instead of inserting new ones with `put`? I tried doing that, but I cannot obtain the ones that are already existing for some reason.

Comment: @ForInfinity Well, there are several problems with that: What you describe would alter the key and thus corrupt the entire internal structure of the `Map`. Distinguishing: How do you know which one are the summed-up values and which are older ones? All you've got are `String, Integer`-pairs, so your best shot would be to mark them somehow and iterate the entire `Map`. Complexity: Why even attempt something this complicated, when simply creating an additional `Map` is so simple?

Comment: create a new map, to reduce complexity. But you could, however, use the existing map. How to distinguish it? Only process the ones that have `size()` more than one

Answer (score 0):

If you want a an end result in following form :
{123-456-789={00:06:06=720}, 999-090-090={00:08:01=900}}
Why not change your loop to something like this by maintaining only one key-value pair in the map:

```
 Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry=dataArray.get(primaryKey).entrySet().iterator().next();
 String key= entry.getKey();
 dataArray.get(primaryKey).put(key + length,    dataArray.get(primaryKey).get(key) + totalCost);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: The compiler doesn't let me get the key of the internal map, suggests to use `Set<String> key` instead but that fails as well.